# Problem while setting up IntelliJ on Macos 10.13.2

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I know for most of you this may seem a simple error, but I couldn't find any answer or a lead to the problem I'm facing, the main reason is that I'm new to `Java Native` and I'm not relevant to error messages or whatever is these message telling me.

When I try to run any code as basic as hello world it prints this line first

> "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
>   "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA
>   CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=49909:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA
>   CE.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath
>   "/Users/marwanabuwasel/Desktop/Java Projects/out/production/Java
>   Projects" Main Hello World again Process finished with exit code 0

I tried to search the message on google a thousand times and always lead me to other problem differ from my problem. I'm using `IntelliJ IDEA Community 2018.2.5`, I installed `JDK` and `JRE` latest versions manually.

Comment: What is the actual problem? There is no error in the message you've provided.

Comment: Can't you just ignore the first line (which is the actual command Intellij uses to run your app)?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, guys as it seems this a normal message by the compiler and I shall ignore it as you said.sorry to bother you all.